# ClearCanvas ImageServer 2.0

Tags: clearcanvas

I have installed the ClearCanvas ImageServer 2.0 with IE8 on Windows 7 32 bits.

I have also installed the Microsoft ASP.NET AJAX Extensions 1.0 and the ASP.NET.

When doing //local../ImageServer it appears a blank page and a text saying:

Version 2.0.12.655.37768 [stand-alone]
User ID:
Password: 
and the Login button.

I think something is messing beacuase the page is all blank.
I think is not loading all the page.
Can someone help me.
All advises will be appreciated.

PS: I was trying to load a picture but this site do not let me load the picture...

Regards,

Comment: You need more rep to include images in your posts - link to the image on an external site for now and someone will edit the image into your question for you.

Answer (score 2):

A first suggestion would be to check IIS that it is configured to serve static content.  Since the text boxes are showing, but the background image is not showing, it appears that the problem is static images are not being served up by IIS on the page.

Comment: Hi, 

I went to "control panel" and click on the "Programs"->“Turn Windows features on or off”->"Internet Information Services"->"World Wide Web Services"->"Common HTTP Features"->Then I check the "Static Content".

After do this I tested and it works.

Thanks a lot for the help
Best Regards,

Comment: Please accept the answer, since this fixed the problem for you!  Ie, click the checkmark next to my answer.